# how to set different background for each options in "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect" plugin

Tags: angular, ng-dropdown-multiselect

I am using "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect" npm plugin for my angular project to display multiple selectable dropdown. Is there any way to add background color for each options?

html

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown class="rsvtn_hm_drp_btn restn_drop_pnl" [options]="reservationStatusList" [settings]="mySettings"
                [texts]="myTexts" formControlName="reservationStatus"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

angularjs

```
reservationStatusList: IMultiSelectOption[];
```

need to show each reservation status background color dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass classes in reservationStatusList like this

```
myOptions: IMultiSelectOption[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Option 1', classes: "class-1" },
        { id: 2, name: 'Option 2', classes: "class-2" },
    ];
```

and then define background color in these classes in global css

```
.class-1 { background-color: #FF0000; }
```